# ddccontrol is not working, but it used to work

Tags: drivers, kernel, brightness

I want to change my monitor (Dell S2216H) brightness with commands

```
ddccontrol -p -r 0x10 -w 53
```

This command used to work on 16.10 now it doesn't, but gives this output

```
robing for available monitors.......
Detected monitors :
No monitor supporting DDC/CI available.
If your graphics card need it, please check all the required kernel 
modules are loaded (i2c-dev, and your framebuffer driver).
```

Output of  `ddccontrol -p` is same

```
ddccontrol version 0.4.2
Copyright 2004-2005 Oleg I. Vdovikin (oleg@cs.msu.su)
Copyright 2004-2006 Nicolas Boichat (nicolas@boichat.ch)
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of this program under the terms of the GNU General Public License.

Probing for available monitors.......
Detected monitors :
No monitor supporting DDC/CI available.
If your graphics card need it, please check all the required kernel 
modules are loaded (i2c-dev, and your framebuffer driver).
```

Output of `i2cdetect -l`

```
i2c-3   unknown     i915 gmbus dpc                      N/A
i2c-1   unknown     i915 gmbus vga                      N/A
i2c-6   unknown     DPDDC-D                             N/A
i2c-4   unknown     i915 gmbus dpb                      N/A
i2c-2   unknown     i915 gmbus panel                    N/A
i2c-0   unknown     i915 gmbus ssc                      N/A
i2c-5   unknown     i915 gmbus dpd                      N/A
```

Here is the output of `ddcontrol -p` when it used to work [at pastebin](https://pastebin.com/GfuvkH9k)

It stopped working while I was doing [this process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899821/control-monitor-brightness-with-keyboard-shortcut) described by [Jacob Vlijm](https://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob-vlijm), But after that I've gone through multiple fresh installs but It never worked, the only thing that seems to be different now is I'm running 17.04 but I distinctly remember it working on 16.10 and then failing on fresh installs of 16.10

---

More info

[I2C dev interface - The Linux Kernel Archives](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface)

[Linux Framebuffer Drivers](http://moi.vonos.net/linux/framebuffer-drivers/)

[What are DPDDC-B/C i2c devices?](https://askubuntu.com/q/546488/665251)

---

*Ultimately I'm trying to [achieve this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899821/control-monitor-brightness-with-keyboard-shortcut) but `ddccontrol` needs to work for that*

Answer (score 0):

On my machine (which runs on ubuntu 16.04), `ddccontrol -p` shows nothing, but `sudo ddccontrol -p` shows my monitor.

On 16.04 you must be a member of the `i2c` group to access `/dev/i2c-X` devices. `i2cdetect -l` works because it list i2c buses, it does not try to open them.